# DrawAllocation: Memory allocations within drawing code

Tags: android, performance, lint

Ran new Lint against my code. It came up with a lot of good suggestions, but this one I cannot understand.

> DrawAllocation:
>
> Memory allocations within drawing code
>
> Explanation:
>
> Looks for memory allocations within drawing code.
>   You should avoid allocating objects during a drawing or layout operation. These are called frequently, so a smooth UI can be interrupted by garbage collection pauses caused by the object allocations.
>
> The way this is generally handled is to allocate the needed objects up front and to reuse them for each drawing operation.
>
> Some methods allocate memory on your behalf (such as Bitmap.create), and these should be handled in the same way.

Could anyone help me figure this out?
Explanation with a code sample is more kindful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Lint warning appears when you are allocating memory in a method that is invoked frequently to draw something on the screen. Allocating and deallocating memory can be avoided by allocating the memory up front, which leads to increased performance.

Code example. For example, we have some class that extends `View`. We override its `onDraw()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // following line allocates memory - really bad place for that
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, null);
}
```

We simply want to display some bitmap. But, every time `onDraw()` is called (which happens very often) totally new bitmap is created and memory is allocated. After execution of `onDraw()` this memory will probably be also deallocated. So, Lint will give us a helpful warning here, that this is a performance issue.

We can do it better:

```
private Bitmap bitmap; 

public OurView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   // pre-allocate bitmap so we can use it later
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // much faster - no allocation/deallocation of bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, null);
}
```

Comment: But how can we do that if we are to create a new Bitmap object using Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

Comment: @Chaitanya if you depend on the View size to draw your bitmap, create it in onSizeChanged. Better yet, create it on a background thread in response to onSizeChanged. ;-)